# Eclipse (Mars) doesn't display maven options despite Maven/m2e installation

Tags: eclipse, maven, ubuntu

As stated, Eclipse Mars doesn't display any Maven options (such as creating or converting to a Maven project), despite me having verified that the m2e plugin and Maven 3.0.5 are both installed. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Restart eclipse and click `Help > About Eclipse` then click on *Installation details* button and in plug-ins tab check m2e plugin.

Comment: I followed the steps exactly, and the following results came up when I searched "m2e":

Eclipse m2e (org.eclipse.m2e.workspace.cli), and Eclipse.org - m2e-w2p (org.eclipse.m2e..wtp.overlay(.ui) ).